# VBScript not allowing "{SPACE}"

Tags: vbscript

I was making a .vbs script that allowed me to type a long message on someone else's Notepad++ application so that I could tell that person what he needed to do since he doesn't have much experience with computers.

So this is the script:

```
Set shl = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set strt = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox "Running Script Maker.."
shl.ShellExecute "notepad++.exe", , "C:\Program Files\Notepad++"
Wscript.sleep 2000
strt.SendKeys "H"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "e"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "l"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "l"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "o."
Wscript.sleep 3000
strt.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
strt.SendKeys "Y"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "o"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "u"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "{SPACE}"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "m"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "i"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "g"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "h"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "t"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "{SPACE}"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "t"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "h"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "i"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "n"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "k"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "{SPACE}"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "t"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "h"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "a"
Wscript.sleep 100
strt.SendKeys "t"
Wscript.sleep 100
```

It was going all so smooth until the script reaches the part of the "{SPACE}"
after the "you" part of the message.
Any kind of solution will be handy.I've been annoyed this problem for minutes.

Comment: Instead of this `SendKeys` insanity, you should just write that message in a text file, and then open the text file in Notepad++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `"{SPACE}"` is [not actually supported](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx), that format tends to be for keystrokes that can't be directly represented as a keyboard character.

In your case, you can just use `" "` instead, it seems to work fine.

---

You *may* also want to think about refactoring your code to meke it a little easier to maintain, something like:

```
sub out (pStrt, pStr, pDelay1, pDelay2)
    pos = 1
    while pos <= len (pStr)
        sz = 1
        if mid (pStr, pos, 1) = "{" then
            sz = instr (pos + 1, pStr, "}") + 1
        end if
        pStrt.SendKeys mid (pStr, pos, sz)
        WScript.sleep pDelay1
        pos = pos + sz
    wend
    if pDelay2 > pDelay1 then
        WScript.sleep pDelay2 - pDelay1
    end if
end sub

Set shl = CreateObject ("Shell.Application")
Set strt = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
shl.ShellExecute "notepad.exe", , "C:\"
Wscript.sleep 2000

out strt, "Hello.{ENTER}", 100, 3000
out strt, "You might think that", 100, 0
```

Comment: Thank you. It has been fixed. Dunno why `"{SPACE}"` didn't work, since it worked for me last time I made a script with it involved.